# convert instruction in assembly

Tags: assembly, binary, hex, decimal

I need help converting these instructions. I'm having trouble. It is the supposed to be the same as plugging in. the instruction gives you the instruction. The before gives you the values they are and after is the resulting answer. If destination is a register answer is in hex. these are instruction sets

```
   instruction                                before                 after

  mov ax, num                            ax=0011  num dw 64

     mov ah, dl                     eax=55de edx=00fa

   movsx edx, ax                              ax=0765  edx=0032

   mov ah, al                                  ax=000b

 mov bx, 147                                  bx=ff00

mov edx, offset you                  bx=ff00 you dw 44

  mov bx,[edx]                           edx=0090           

  mov al,32                                   ax=5678

  mov bh,al                                ax=5476 bx=3298

   mov sum,ax                              ax=00aa sum=45

  movzx ecx, 1a                            cx=00a0
```

Comment: Huh? _"Converting instructions"_? To _what_?

Comment: to what the instruction mean in assembly

Answer (score 1):

```
mov ax, num               ax=0011   num dw 64
mov ah, dl                eax=55de  edx=00fa
movsx edx, ax             ax=0765   edx=0032
mov ah, al                ax=000b
mov bx, 147               bx=ff00
mov edx, offset you       bx=ff00   you dw 44            (1)
mov bx,[edx]              edx=0090                       (2)
mov al,32                 ax=5678
mov bh,al                 ax=5476   bx=3298
mov sum,ax                ax=00aa   sum=45
movzx ecx, 1a             cx=00a0                        (3)
```

For (1),(2), and (3) you don't have enough information to solve the **after** problem.
All other lines are just about numbers that move around. Should be easy enough.